# MySQL query to retrieve data from multiple tables as nested tree

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance

Found similar questions on SO, but nothing that helped. Here's my problem:

I have a table, 'events', that will be rather large.
Also there are these two tables: 'photos' and 'videos'.
Every 'events' record has an eid (event id).
Every 'photos' and 'videos' record has an aeid (associated event id).

To grab event data of say 20 events, I'm currently running PHP like so:

```
array = get top 20 events
for these 20 events
  array['photos'] = get all photos
  array['videos'] = get all videos
return events array
```

I'm finding out that this is running too slow. Probably because that equates to 41 mysql queries. I realize I need use JOIN somehow (I think I do at least), but I can't figure our how to structure my query so that it nested the photos and videos in the same way that I'm doing it in the pseudocode above. Also, I don't think I have the time to spare to switch over to postgres (unless it is very highly suggested); I'm working with a large enough codebase for that to be a headache with only one dev (me).

I'm willing to read documents/manuals if you post them. But, I've already done so in a few places to no avail. Thanks!

Comment: Did my answer below help?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like..

```
 SELECT E.eid, V.aeid, P.aeid 
 FROM events E, videos V, photos P 
 WHERE E.eid='$ID' and V.aeid='$ID' and P.aeid='$ID' 
 ORDER BY E.eid desc
```

Untested, but you should get the point

Comment: It's return 0 results. I think that's because it assumes every event has at least one video and photo. Is that why? Also, I don't see how this will nest the photos and videos of an event inside the event output. (I suppose the latter can be done with php)

Comment: That's just a simple example you can use instead of join. You should post your current sql queries so I can further help you.

Comment: thanks, but the current queries are in ActiveRecord statements because I'm using CodeIgniter. I'd have to post the whole php file for them to make any sense (and i can't do that). Is there a way to go through all the event rows in the result and subquery to add the photo to a 'photos' alias/col and same for videos?